# Count no-NA values per row

Tags: r, data.table

```
family_id<-c(1,2,3)
age_mother<-c(30,27,29)
dob_child1<-c("1998-11-12","1999-12-12","1996-04-12")##child one birth day
dob_child2<-c(NA,"1997-09-09",NA)##if no child，NA
dob_child3<-c(NA,"1999-09-01","1996-09-09")
DT<-data.table(family_id,age_mother,dob_child1,dob_child2,dob_child3)
```

Now I have DT, how can I use this table to know how many children each family have using syntax like this:

```
DT[,apply..,keyby=family_id]##this code is wrong
```

Comment: Could either do `DT[, 3 - Reduce("+", lapply(.SD, is.na)), .SDcols = dob_child1:dob_child3]` or `DT[, rowSums(!is.na(.SD)), .SDcols = dob_child1:dob_child3]`

Comment: Delete quotes on `NA` in `dob_child3` if no is recognized as a date and counted

Comment: you can also melt and count: `melt(DT, measure.vars = patterns("^dob_child"))[!is.na(value), .(kids = .N), by= family_id]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks a lot. Your answer is really what I want. It is a direct solution. And I make some change to DT[, .(family_id,rowSums(!is.na(.SD))),.SDcols = dob_child1:dob_child3]

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks. Your answer is quite inspiring.

Comment: @DavidArenburg your comment is great but I don't not how to accept it. Can I "accept" your comment?

Comment: You can't accept a comment. You can answer it yourself if you feel like. I don't feel like posting an answer so I don't care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may also work:

```
> DT$total_child <- as.vector(rowSums(!is.na(DT[, c("dob_child1", 
"dob_child2", "dob_child3")])))
> DT
  family_id age_mother dob_child1 dob_child2 dob_child3 total_child
1         1         30 1998-11-12       <NA>       <NA>           1
2         2         27 1999-12-12 1997-09-09 1999-09-01           3
3         3         29 1996-04-12       <NA> 1996-09-09           2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqldf` package, to use a `SQL` query in `R`.

I duplicated your DT.

```
family_id<-c(1,2,3)
age_mother<-c(30,27,29)
dob_child1<-c("1998-11-12","1999-12-12","1996-04-12")##child one birth day
dob_child2<-c(NA,"1997-09-09",NA)##if no child，NA
dob_child3<-c(NA,"1999-09-01","1996-09-09")
DT<-data.table(family_id,age_mother,dob_child1,dob_child2,dob_child3)

library(sqldf)

sqldf('select distinct (count(dob_child3)+count(dob_child2)+count(dob_child1)) as total_child,
       family_id from DT group by family_id')
```

The result is the following:

```
  total_child family_id
1           1         1
2           3         2
3           2         3
```

It is correct for you?